# Variables not equivalent fstream vs. declaration

Tags: c++, lua

Basically I'm reading the contents of a file using fstream then converting it to const char* type.  I'm supplying this to Lua, and Lua will do something with this.  This however does not work.  What does work is if I do:

```
const char* data = "print('Hello world')";
luaL_pushstring(L, data);
luaL_setglobal(L, "z");
```

They both are in the type const char* type and they are both the same string (e.g. I compared the two lengths).  Except one works, and the other.  I'm baffled.  Any help here?  Here is the code:

```
   std::string line,text;
   std::ifstream in("test.txt");
   while(std::getline(in, line))
   {
       text += line;
   }
   const char* data = text.c_str();
   luaL_pushstring(L, data);
   luaL_setglobal(L, "z");
```

Here is the Lua code:

```
loadstring(z)()
```

Comment: You've given a code snippet of the thing that works; could you also give a snippet of the thing that doesn't?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to help you with the bit that doesn't work when you only post the bit that does work.

Comment: I think we also need to see the Lua code that does "something" with the string; and rather than just saying "works" / "doesn't work", describe what you expected to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working' - what do you expect an what do you see?  Also, there's no `lua_pushstring()` in your first example - are you sure that code is 'working'?

Comment: In the first sample, you didn't push on the data- you just set the global. In the second, you pushed on, then set the global. The state of the Lua stack is not the same at the time that setglobal is called. @Zack: Good luck trying to understand the Lua source.

Comment: I've put up the full source code.

Comment: @Camoy: You tried to execute a comment. What exact result are you expecting? Secondly, why not just use the built-in Lua API file loading routines?

Comment: Is ***text*** going out of scope and being free()'ed?  Perhaps this would be a good place to use strdup()?

Comment: @DeadMG For some reason use luaL_loadstring doesn't perform the expected result.  I did not try to execute a comment look again.

Comment: @Mr.Ree Nah, I just did a cout before luaL_pushstring and it printed correctly.

Comment: I understand lua_pushstring() should create a copy of the string.  I'm not familiar with luaL_pushstring.  Does it also create a copy?   The situation I'm concerned with is where lua stores a pointer to your string, which subsequently goes out of scope creating a referential transparency.  In this situation, you could cout (print) your string *after* calling luaL_pushstring and it would print correctly.  However, subsequent access in lua would point to free'd and potentially  re-used memory.

Comment: There's no luaL_pushstring and luaL_setglobal in the Lua API. There is lua_pushstring and lua_setglobal though.

Comment: @Mr.Ree: No, the pointer remains valid as long as the std::string doesn't resize. lua uses string pooling and thus always makes a separate copy of all strings pushed to it, or not, as necessary.

Comment: So Lua is replicating the string.  Not an issue then.  Regarding the pointer remaining valid:  If the std::string goes out of scope, and your code was declaring it on the stack, then the pointer is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

To diagnose this, you probably want to know more about what Lua thought. I'd write the Lua side as `assert(loadstring(s))()` instead. If `loadstring` fails, your current code at best prints an error from the attempt to call `nil`. With the `assert()` in the sequence, the call to `nil` will be replaced by a more informative error about what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to set the global before you push the value?  Anyways, what's up, Camoy :P